# Auto-reminder for three people

Tags: gmail, notifications, automation

Need to set an auto-reminder once daily for three people. Seems like a simple task but Microsoft Outlook needs to be running in order to do it. Also, I seem to run into roadblocks doing it with a lot of online services because of issues preventing spam.

What is a good way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged GMail so that means you should be able to use Google Calendar to create a daily repeating event.  Set reminders as needed then invite the 3 attendees.

You can set SMS, local or e-mail reminders on all Google Calendar Events.

Comment: Ah, I think that will work. Thanks so much!